# Multiple VMExtensions per handler not supported for OS type 'Linux

Tags: mongodb, azure, azure-storage, redhat, azure-resource-manager

I have created Azure VM using ARM template. Now I want to install Java and Mongodb on Azure VM.

When I try to use Multiple CustomScript, I get the following error.

```
Multiple VMExtensions per handler not supported for OS type 'Linux
```

Below are my configuration:-

parameters:-

```
"javaPackageName": {
    "type": "string",
    "defaultValue": "openjdk-7-jdk",
    "allowedValues": [
        "openjdk-6-jdk",
        "openjdk-7-jdk",
        "openjdk-8-jdk"
    ]
},
"tomcatPackageName": {
    "type": "string",
    "defaultValue": "tomcat7",
    "allowedValues": [
    "tomcat6",
    "tomcat7",
    "tomcat8"
    ]
}
```

variables:-

"mongoInstallCentos": "https:/..install-mongo.json"

```
{
    "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions",
    "name": "[concat(parameters('virtualMachineName'),'/javainstall')]",
    "apiVersion": "2015-05-01-preview",
    "location": "[variables('location')]",
    "dependsOn": [
        "[concat('Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/', parameters('virtualMachineName'))]"
    ],
    "properties": {
        "publisher": "Microsoft.Azure.Extensions",
        "type": "CustomScript",
        "typeHandlerVersion": "2.0",
        "autoUpgradeMinorVersion": true,
        "settings": {
        "fileUris": ["https://..java-tomcat-install.sh"],
        "commandToExecute": "[concat('sh java-tomcat-install.sh',' ',parameters('javaPackageName'),' ',parameters('tomcatPackageName'))]"
        }
    }
},
{
    "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions",
    "name": "[concat(parameters('virtualMachineName'),'/mongoinstall')]",
    "apiVersion": "2015-05-01-preview",
    "location": "[variables('location')]",
    "dependsOn": [
        "[concat('Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/', parameters('virtualMachineName'))]"
    ],
    "properties": {
        "publisher": "Microsoft.Azure.Extensions",
        "type": "CustomScript",
        "typeHandlerVersion": "2.0",
        "autoUpgradeMinorVersion": true,
        "settings": {
        "fileUris": ["https://..mongo-install.sh"],
        "commandToExecute": "sh mongo-install.sh"
        }
    }
},
```

Is there any solution use Multiple CustomScript in ARM template? Kindly help me to solve this.

Comment: you can probably chain those using nested templates

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Multiple VMExtensions per handler not supported for OS type 'Linux

Currently , it is not possible to run Multiple  CustomScript Extensions at the  deployment time.

According to your scenario,  you can author an entry point script that calls the dependent scripts, then upload the entry point script, dependent scripts and any other dependent binaries to the script location(Azure storage blob or GitHub). More information please refer to this [link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/automate-linux-vm-customization-tasks-using-customscript-extension/).

Also, you could refer to this similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42206705/azure-extension-script-for-linux/42216716#42216716).