# Azure : create file through template

Tags: azure-rm-template

We have a requirement where a config file is to be created and sent to a linux VM for later setup. Is there is any way of doing that. We are using ARM template for the setup

Comment: Azure ARM template does not support create config file directly. In your scenario, I suggest you could use Azure Custom Script Extension. Using a script to create a config file and store it to a specify path on linux.

Comment: @ShengbaoShui-MSFT But how will I pass value of User input to config file

Comment: You pass value when you deploy template? Using echo "">config.file

Comment: You could use parameters like `"commandToExecute" : "[concat('sh script_executor.sh \"', parameters('cmdToExecute') '\"')]"`

Comment: You could create a script to receive parameters and modify your config file. Hope it helps.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42206705/azure-extension-script-for-linux

Comment: If you want to pass multiple values, you could use multiple parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If my understanding is right, you could use [Azure Custom Script Extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/extensions-customscript) to do this.

> The Custom Script Extension downloads and executes scripts on Azure
>   virtual machines. This extension is useful for post deployment
>   configuration, software installation, or any other configuration /
>   management task. Scripts can be downloaded from Azure storage or other
>   accessible internet location, or provided to the extension run time.

Example

```
{
    "name": "scriptextensiondemo",
    "type": "extensions",
    "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
    "apiVersion": "2015-06-15",
    "dependsOn": [
        "[concat('Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/', parameters('scriptextensiondemoName'))]"
    ],
    "tags": {
        "displayName": "scriptextensiondemo"
    },
    "properties": {
        "publisher": "Microsoft.Azure.Extensions",
        "type": "CustomScript",
        "typeHandlerVersion": "2.0",
        "autoUpgradeMinorVersion": true,
      "settings": {
        "fileUris": [
          "https://gist.github.com/ahmetalpbalkan/b5d4a856fe15464015ae87d5587a4439/raw/466f5c30507c990a4d5a2f5c79f901fa89a80841/hello.sh"
        ],
        "commandToExecute": "sh hello.sh"
      }
    }
}
```

You could create a script to create the file and execute Linux commands.

Comment: This I know and it can create or download a file from fileuri and run it. My problem is that I need to create a text file based on user's input and then pass it on to VM as config file.

Comment: Hi Shen, I am able to get data to my image using customdata. But it is stored in waagent folder and I am not able to access it due to permission error. How to get past that??

Comment: @BlindSniper Custom script extension is executed as user root. In your script, I suggest you could access the waagent file and get the value you want. Don't use `sudo`.